# What does It Mean to Find Norm under a Hessian?

Tags: gradient-descent

$E[ \lVert \nabla f(x)\rVert^2_{\nabla^2 f(x) ^{-1}}]$

This is explained as a norm of gradient and a measure of its magnitude under the hessian.

I have no idea what it means and would appreciate any changes to the question or explanation.

Comment: If A is a positive definite matrix and x is a real vector then $\| x \|_A=(x^T A x)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Is there a name for this operator? if I had to search for this

Comment: The (vector) norm induced by A.